# Android App crashes when trying to ramdomize string

Tags: android, android-studio

No errors on android studio but crashes when trying to show random sentence on Text View. So I am a beginner and trying to do app that randomizes sentence, this crashes on every emulator and phone I've tried it on, what could be the problem?
Thanks for answers in advance!

Game.java :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        final String[] lauseet = {"Moro moro", "Tere tere", "Heippa hei",     "Nakkimuki ja vesi"};

        final int rando = (int) (Math.random()*4);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                textView2.setText(lauseet[rando]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And

The xml file for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="fi.itsn.junttipeli.Game">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Tämä on väitekenttä"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:onClick="klikk"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seuraava"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="klikk"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the exact error that is shown in your logcat?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see any real (read error causing) problem with the code but, I think based on your intent, you are looking for something like:

```
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final String[] lauseet = {"Moro moro", "Tere tere", "Heippa hei", "Nakkimuki ja vesi"};
    final Random random = new Random();

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView2.setText(lauseet[random.nextInt(4)]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Replace 4 with lauseet.length

Answer (score 0):

Your String array have only 4 items in it , when you create random number your multiplying double value with the 4 which may return some value like 4.1253527  when you set that random value to index of the string which may cause **out of bounds exception** when you click on the button solution is

```
Random ran= new Random();
int rando = ran.nextInt(4);// here it will return the random number between 1 to 4
```

Comment: I was thinking that but, `Math.random()` won't return anything larger than 1.0 and hence the ultimate result cannot be more than 4.

Comment: Math.random() will return value from 0.0 to 1.0 random value of double Reference check this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_random.htm

Comment: Yes I understand that... what I don't understand is how can a value <= 1.0 be more than 4.0 when multiplied by 4.

Comment: @Shaishav, if the returned value is 1? index 4 will throw index out of bound Exception.

Comment: Agree, but didn't OP say the app *"crashes on every emulator and phone I've tried it on"*...What are the odds of that?

Comment: @Shaishav, Thats a valid point. But we can only make sure that by seeing the log.

Comment: So you can change the multiple of 4 into 3 which may prevent from out of bounds like here int rando = (int) (Math.random()*3);

Comment: No. Casting a double to an int, causes the int to be floored. So [0,1) becomes [0-4) always rounded down.  The range is from 0.0 inclusive to 1.0 exclusive (you won't get 1.0 ever). So when it's floored it will *always* give either 0,1,2,3 and these numbers will be properly and equally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

The code as presented is pretty weak and should be something more like:

```
static final String[] lauseet = {"Moro moro", "Tere tere", "Heippa hei",     "Nakkimuki ja vesi"};
Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView2.setText(lauseet[random.nextInt(lauseet.length)]);
        }
    });
}
```

Though really the lauseet values should be an TypedArray in xml.

But the main point is it works fine as is with no crash.

There is no crash. Post the logcat with the crash and the file that is actually crashing, very likely it's in xml or your namespace is wrong or something.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html
See: View the system log

https://youtu.be/Jo18aTnvdhI

---

PS. To the comment debate:
Casting a double to an int, causes the int to be floored. So [0,1) becomes [0-4) always rounded down. The range is from 0.0 inclusive to 1.0 exclusive (you won't get 1.0 ever). So when it's floored it will always give either 0,1,2,3 and these numbers will be properly and equally distributed.